# PerforceChangeList : error : No matching clients for root

Tags: c++, visual-studio, jenkins, perforce

I am syncing and building a project using jenkins with msbuild tool, but I keep getting this error everytime I run the build, either in VS or through Jenkins. I honestly have no idea what it means and I have not found any information on internet. I have another very similar project which runs fine. Any help or what to start checking it would be much appreciated as I have delete and set the job from scratch with the same result. This is the output I get from jenkins:

```
"C:\Users\User\.jenkins\workspace\Age_3_DE\Source\Age3DE.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\User\.jenkins\workspace\Age_3_DE\Source\age3\age3.vcxproj" (default target) (2) ->
(PreBuildEvent target) -> 
  PerforceChangeList : error : No matching clients for root=C:\Users\User\.jenkins\workspace\Age_3_DE\ [C:\Users\User\.jenkins\workspace\Age_3_DE\Source\age3\age3.vcxproj]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(128,5): error MSB3073: The command "C:\Users\User\.jenkins\workspace\Age_3_DE\Source\..\Scripts\PerforceChangeList.bat age3 "C:\Users\User\.jenkins\workspace\Age_3_DE\Source\age3\PerforceVersion.inc" "C:\Users\User\.jenkins\workspace\Age_3_DE\Source\age3\resource_version.h" [C:\Users\User\.jenkins\workspace\Age_3_DE\Source\age3\age3.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(128,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code -1. [C:\Users\User\.jenkins\workspace\Age_3_DE\Source\age3\age3.vcxproj]

    27 Warning(s)
    2 Error(s)
```

resource_version.h file:

```
#pragma once  
#define VERSION_MAJOR 100  
#define VERSION_MINOR 10  
#define VERSION_BUILD 0  
#define VERSION_STRING "100.10.0.0"
```

and PerforceVersion.inc:

```
#pragma once 
namespace PerforceInfo { 
   const char* gChangeList = "00000"; 
   const char* gVersionString = "100.10.0.0"; 
   const char* gUserName = ""; 
   const char* gClientName = ""; 
   const char* gClientHost = ""; 
   const char* gClientRoot = ""; 
   const char* gClientStream = ""; 
}
```

Here is an image with the exactly error and the line where the error happens from VS [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11hC4.png)

Comment: Please check on your `ag3.vcxproj` file and find a command which called it. The error on that code, `The command "C:\Users\User\.jenkins\workspace\Age_3_DE\Source\..\Scripts\PerforceChangeList.bat age3 "C:\Users\User\.jenkins\workspace\Age_3_DE\Source\age3\PerforceVersion.inc" "C:\Users\User\.jenkins\workspace\Age_3_DE\Source\age3\resource_version.h" [C:\Users\User\.jenkins\workspace\Age_3_DE\Source\age3\age3.vcxproj]`.

Comment: So please check this command on your `ag3.vcxproj` file and make sure that the command which your write has no grammatical errors. Also, make sure that `PerforceChangeList.bat` file is right and its content has no error.

Comment: thanks for your comments. The ```PerforceChangeList.bat``` is fine and it has no errors. I cannot find the coomand on my ```age3.vcxproj``` as it is a whole project with many dependencies

Comment: Did these file `C:\Users\User\.jenkins\workspace\Age_3_DE\Source\age3\resource_version.h` and `C:\Users\User\.jenkins\workspace\Age_3_DE\Source\age3\PerforceVersion.inc` exist?

Comment: they both exist

Comment: added to the main message